# PHP preg_match matching everything?

Tags: php, preg-match

The below code is returning a match for any $name variable I use. Would anyone mind explaining why and the necessary correction? Thank you!

```
$name = 'Johns Donuts';

if (preg_match("/INTERNAL USE ONLY | /",$name) ==1 ) {

    echo 'I match internal use only: '.$name.'';

} else {

    echo 'I DONT match internal use only: '.$name.'';
}
```

Comment: `| ` is almost certainly your problem, what ar eyou trying to match with this?

Comment: @MarkBaker   Thank you - The pipe character is sometimes in the subject term ($name) and not intended to be used as an operator in the pattern match. Escaping the character works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the pipe character, which if memory serves correctly, is effectively an "or" operator. Given the other side is a space, that matches somewhere in your string.

Solution: escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Thank you - I thought I tried that however I was mistaken. Escaping it with the backslash works.